# Finding the area by the graph by the parametric equations.

Tags: calculus, integration

I know how to find the graphs of an equation using integration.  For example:

The area of $f(x)=x^2$ from $x=1$ to $x=2$ is $\int^2_1 x^2dx$.

Is it possible to find the area of parametric equations, but how do we do that?

For example, how would I be able to find the area given by the parametric equations:

$$y=\sin(t^2),\ x=\sin(t)?$$

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by area in this case? What are your limits for $t$? Check [this](http://bit.ly/13cIkWO) picture to see what's confusing.

Comment: @Kaster -- the plot linked to in your comment has $x=\sin(t^2)$ compared to OP $x=\sin(t)$. (Of course one can just flip the graph through $y=x$.)

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, you're right. But my question was what exactly in this case is area, since for different ranges if $t$ curve might be extremely convoluted.

Comment: @Kaster Yes, area is a problem, and the curve is a scribble even for $0\le t \le 2\pi$. Maybe one could mean the total area of the finite (bounded) portions of the plane determined by the parametric graph, once one fixes on a particular range $t \in [a,b]$ for which $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$ and some number of equalities $\gamma(s)=\gamma(t)$ for $s,t \in [a,b]$ at which the curve crossed itself. Then total area cut off would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

If your curve was closed and periodic, you can use polar coordinates:
$$r(\theta)=\sqrt{\sin^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta^2)}$$
So the area is given by the integral:
$$A = \int_0^{2\pi} r(\theta) r dr d\theta$$ 
In your case, as Kaster noted, $r(\theta)$ is not single valued which rather complicates matters. In fact, the curve is non repeating, since it will never return to $t = 0$. If it would, then you would have $t = m\pi$ and $t^2 = n\pi$, which would lead to $\pi$ being rational. Thus, for your example, the area is only defined for small segments of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

let $x=f(t)$ and $y= g(t)$ then  area of parametric equations is equal to :$$A=\int g(t) f '(t) dt$$

Proof :let $y=S(x)$ and $a\le x \le b$ then$$ A=\int_a^b S(x)dx=\int_c^d S(f(t))d(f(t))=\int_c^d g(t)f '(t)dt$$
such that $c=f(a)$ and $d=f(b$)

for more detail see [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/ParaArea.aspx)

> $$\int_{a}^{b}\cos(t)sin^2(t)dt=\int_{\sin(a)}^{\sin(b)} u^2du=\frac{(\sin(b))^3}{3}-\frac{(\sin(a))^3}{3}$$

Comment: So, if you take $a = 0$ and $b = \pi$, your area will be zero? May I ask you same question I was asking OP, what exactly is area in that case?

Comment: @ Kaster:there is no problem for example let $x=\theta$ and $ y=cos(\theta)$ then $A=\int_{0}^{\pi}cos(\theta)=0$

Comment: @ MaisamHedyelloo, please look at the plots of $\{\theta,\cos \theta\}$ and $\{\sin t, \sin t^2\}$, and tell me, which one reveals concept of area more clearly. That's first thing. But even then, you silently assume that area under the $x$ axis has a negative value. This is OK, as it is a matter of convention. But now, again look at the plot of $\{\sin t, \sin^2 t\}$ to decide whether upper and lower parts of it wrt to $x$ axis are equal to each other. Especially if one counts region that curve crosses twice.

Comment: Ok, so here's what I meant. Please, take a look at [this](http://i.imgur.com/u3JrsqY.png) image. One clearly see that upper- and lower-from-$x$ axis parts are not equal, so it's not quite clear why integral you've provided should be linked to signed (above is positive, below is negative) area concept.